# Can rabbits make babies when separated by a single wire cage wall?

Tags: rabbits, breeding, enclosure, pregnancy

I have heard several people say that their female rabbit got pregnant while physically separated from the buck by a wire cage. I have heard it from multiple people, over a span of years. In all cases there was a single wire fence dividing the two.  At first I suspected the person accidently allowed full contact, but I am beginning to wonder.

It is easy enough to imagine impregnation with a bipedal animal separated only by wire cage (*given appropriate size openings in the cage*). But it is difficult to imagine in a four legged animal like a rabbit.

Are there any validated occurrence of rabbit pregnancy, where separation between doe and buck was a wire cage or similar? If so what types of wire separation can be shown to be effective or in-effective in preventing pregnancy.

Related [Pet Rabbits, Double Pregnacies, and Keeping the Buck in with the Doe](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6581)

Comment: I can't see any way this would be possible. I agree that the people making this claim are confused.