# Why are my rabbits dying?

Tags: rabbits

I am a rabbit breeder in Southern CA. And recently two of my does (American Blue), and ( New Zealand White), both gave birth to litters on the 14th of this month. They are both good and experienced mothers, that  take very good care of their kits, produce plenty of milk, and prepare good nests, with plenty of fur. The bucks that they were bread with are also proven and are very good breeders. But for some reason I am loosing at least one kit every day!!! The first litter was a litter of 5( which I think is a pretty good size), while the second litter had 10( to me that is a big litter) so far we are down to 1 baby in each litter, and I am desperate to find out what on earth is going on. If the does loose their last babies( which are currently healthy, with full tummies and moving about, and warm) then I will have two does full of milk, but they will have no means to get rid of the milk which could lead to infections. Please if anyone has any idea of what I can try, or what may be wrong please let me know.
Ruth

Comment: Also related [Why are my Baby bunnies Dying?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12208/why-are-my-baby-bunnies-dying)